# C#/.Net Create Excel File From XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel

I have seen a working example in past where some data/xml data was created. However it was saved with .xls extension. So when we open it, it was an excel file.

I don't remember how the xml tags were formed or what they were. I've searched and looked around but haven't succeeded yet.

I don't want to use any library, either one free from microsoft or open source or any other third party one, to do this thing.

Anyone has any idea about acomplishing this ?

Comment: Are you thinking of an [Open XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) file?

Comment: I got a working example from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2005/06/27/433152.aspx However one thing is bothering me and that is the message which is displayed when you open the file "The file format and extension of 'ExcelSample.xls' don't match. "The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?"

Comment: I really wonder how this question gets voted up, as it doesn't show any research effort, no coding effort and is in my opinion to broad...

Comment: I think its a genuine problem one that will benefit a lot of peoples. A questoin that is not asked before. It adds value. As far as research effort is concerned I have clearly mentioned "I've searched and looked around" that is the reason why I've found a working example as well which I've posted here as well. The scope is not broad. It has been narrowed down to Open Xml as pointed out by TVOHM.

Comment: Isn't the file extension for Open XML .xlsx and not .xls?

Comment: @ItsZeus then show your effort in what you have tried already and where you run into problems, this here is an opinion based question and their are quite some ways how you can resolve your problem

Comment: @Icepickle there's no way to show R&D effort. However still I put in the solution I found which is off course part of my R&D effort. Secondly If you read my comment you will see an issue I am facing if i try the solution. That is coding effort for you. Using xml to create an excel file is pretty narrowed down scope. Its not opinion based. One can't create html to be opened as excel file when its explicitly mentioned to use XML.

Comment: To help understand your issue, what is your aversion to using libraries?  There are numerous out there that will do this task for you quickly and easily, so it would help to understand why those are off limits.  If this an academic exercise, or is there a licensing issue for your project that precludes the use?  Can you use COM/Interop?

Comment: I want to use this approach because of following advantages Advantages. 
No training. 
Less time required for development.
Is open standard. 
Less coding required. 
A new dll/library is not required to be added to project. 
No update required.
Platform independent.